# Inline CSS from a valid CSS file (less or sass)

Tags: css, sass, less

I normally use **lessc**  to minify CSS, e.g.

```
lessc -x source.css > compressed.css
```

And source.css contains

```
@import url("another.css"); // Valid CSS
p {
   /* Some random CSS */
   color:red;
}
```

Which give me

```
@import url("another.css");p{color:#f00}
```

I want to take the **another.css** as inline markup in compressed.css, the only way I know is to use..

```
@import (inline) "another.css"; // Not valid CSS
```

However, this line is not a valid CSS, so when I include **source.css** directly and it will be broken.

Are there any way such as the source.css keep as valid CSS (useful for development), but compressed.css will be optimized as inline CSS?

Note: I don't use less' functionalities, so if SASS can provide the same functionality I am open to listen.

Comment: So are you using LESS or Sass?

Answer (score 0):

Use [clean-css](https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css) instead, if you're not using less at all. It can automatically follow `@import`s. Just use `@import url("another.css");` in your source.css and use:

```
cleancss source.css > compressed.css
```

If another.css is:

```
h1 {
    color: #eee;
}
```

It outputs:

```
h1{color:#eee}p{color:red}
```